# What is best way to get all UnicodeBlocks?

Tags: java

I need to iterate over all instances of the `Character.UnicodeBlock`. For some weird reason it is not an enum. How can I get the values inside a Collection or array. The HashMap that holds them all is private.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems there's no way to get access to these things without reflection, unless someone proves me wrong.

So here's how to get a `List<UnicodeBlock>`:

```
   List<UnicodeBlock> collect = Arrays.stream(UnicodeBlock.class.getFields())
                                 .filter(f -> f.getType() == UnicodeBlock.class)
                                 .map(field -> {
                                   try {
                                     return (UnicodeBlock)field.get(null);
                                   } catch (IllegalAccessException e) {
                                     throw new RuntimeException(e);
                                   }
                                 })
                                 .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

Exceptions in lambdas are always ugly, but it does the job.